# Count sum of values in JSON array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Having an array like this:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "Dave",
        "coins": 14,
        "weapons": 2,
        "otherItems": 3,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vanessa",
        "coins": 18,
        "weapons": 1,
        "otherItems": 5,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sharon",
        "coins": 9,
        "weapons": 5,
        "otherItems": 1,
        "color": "pink"
    },
    {
        "name": "Walter",
        "coins": 9,
        "weapons": 2,
        "otherItems": 4,
        "color": "white"
    }
]
```

How to count sum of `coins`, `weapons` and `otherItems` using ES6 features? (I'm not attached to this: any simple method would be good.)

`data.reduce((first, last) => first + last)` generates a chain of `[object Object][object Object]`s...

Comment: what do you like to count? do you have an example of the result?

Comment: All the countable values :-) As I wrote, `coins`, `weapons` and `otherItems`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an array of wanted keys for the sums and create an object for the sums and add the wanted values.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Dave", coins: 14, weapons: 2, otherItems: 3, color: "red" }, { name: "Vanessa", coins: 18, weapons: 1, otherItems: 5, color: "blue" }, { name: "Sharon", coins: 9, weapons: 5, otherItems: 1, color: "pink" }, { name: "Walter", coins: 9, weapons: 2, otherItems: 4, color: "white" }],
    keys = ['coins', 'weapons', 'otherItems'],
    sums = data.reduce(
        (r, o) => (keys.forEach(k => r[k] += o[k]), r), 
        Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, 0]))
    );

console.log(sums);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to process every field separately (note that when you don't specify second parameter for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it will take first array object as seed and start processing from the second one):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "Dave",
        "coins": 14,
        "weapons": 2,
        "otherItems": 3,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "name": "Vanessa",
        "coins": 18,
        "weapons": 1,
        "otherItems": 5,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sharon",
        "coins": 9,
        "weapons": 5,
        "otherItems": 1,
        "color": "pink"
    },
    {
        "name": "Walter",
        "coins": 9,
        "weapons": 2,
        "otherItems": 4,
        "color": "white"
    }
]

let result = data.reduce((a,c)=> ({ 
     coins: a.coins + c.coins, 
     weapons: a.weapons + c.weapons, 
     otherItems: a.otherItems + c.otherItems })
)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: To provide coverage for the case of a single object in the array you'll need to provide an initialValue `reduce((a,c)=> { ... }, {coins: 0, weapons: 0, otherItems: 0})`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` for this.

To make it a little bit more flexible and dynamic, make a `Set` of keys you want to get a count of.

Then go through each *key* in the `Set` and if that key is in the `obj`, sum it up in an `accumulator` object in the reduce callback:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Dave","coins":14,"weapons":2,"otherItems":3,"color":"red"},{"name":"Vanessa","coins":18,"weapons":1,"otherItems":5,"color":"blue"},{"name":"Sharon","coins":9,"weapons":5,"otherItems":1,"color":"pink"},{"name":"Walter","coins":9,"weapons":2,"otherItems":4,"color":"white"}]

//Keys to count
const keys = new Set(["coins", "weapons", "otherItems"]);

const count = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const objKeys = keys.forEach(key => {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + obj[key];
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right, you need to use `reduce` method. The problem is that you're summing two objects, not their properties. All you need to do is change the code to the following (to sum the coins):

```js
data.reduce((first, last) => first.coins + last.coins, 0)
```

And following for weapons:

```js
data.reduce((first, last) => first.weapons + last.weapons, 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives `NaN` as a result. @mickl's answer seems to be right.

Comment: I forgot the initial value, edited the answer now, so it should be working

Comment: Still `NaN` here... The accumulator (`first`) shouldn't refer to any key: this will work: `data.reduce((first, last) => first + last.coins, 0)`.